# Streams, Queue or Bloc for TCP communication in flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am new to flutter/dart and in the process of developing an app that communicates with a video projector device. I am unsure with the choice of the right way to implement (TCP socket) communication with the devcie.

There are a couple of challenges:

1. The device only support one single connection, it rejects other connection attempts.
2. After establishing a TCP connection a handshake pocedure has to be done, so for issuing commands in short intervals I want to keep the connection open
3. After sending a command the projector always sends and ACK sequence and depending on the command a seconds message with a result. While this command/response procedure the projector does not accept other command, they are simply ignored without feedback
4. The projector does not send any data without requests, so I have to do polling for updates of powerstate, input and so on. Each cycle of polling is about a dozen of requests and takes a couple of seconds so complete so to remain responsive for accepting commands polling hat do be done in the background

1 and 2 are quite straightforward to implement but with 3 and 4 I have my struggles.

I thought of three different approaches. In every case I have:

```
class ProjectorDevice { … }

abstract class Action { … }
class ActionConnect extends Action { … }
class ActionReadSetting extends Action { … }
class ActionSendCommand extends Action { … }
…
```

Approach 1: Streams

In my ProjectorDevice class I listen to a stream with the actions. The actions are added to the stream by user interaction or by timer events for the polling of data.

Problem 1: Streams are generally handled in parallel which is not supported by the projector device.

I could use a package like synchronized to lock the access to the projector?

Problem 2: If a timer event "queues" a dozen ActionReadSetting the projector is busy and will not respond to an ActionSendCommand from the user (change input for example)

Since I cannot insert "priority" commands in an existing stream I though of have two streams: stdActionStream and prioActionStream but I do not know how to listen to both streams where data in the prioActionStream always take precendence regardless of the time they were added to the stream.

Approach 2: Bloc

I find Bloc quite interesting but my head starts spinnig when trying to split my classes in Blocs and Cubits. The projector setting objects could be Cubits to easily support change to notifications is the UI.

But I am not sure if using a Bloc for the ProjectorConnection makes sense. I can queue the Actions as events and achieve a similar result as with streams (with the same problem with priority messages). But as soon as the projector is connected the Bloc state does not change anymore (except for errors or disconnect)

Approach 3: Queue

With a queue (or two queues) managed by an ActionQueue class I could work around the listen() issues with streams. But how do I "drive" the queue? Are Isolates here the way to go? The dart sample long_running_isolate.dart looks like it could be a quite good fit.

Long story short I think the third approach make most sense but I really would like to have feedback before heading in the wrong direction.